# PHP - Submit form through Ajax function after button click

Tags: php, html, ajax

I have a form that is currently submitted to a database via an Ajax function after submitting. However, I want to change this by adding a 'Save' button that will save the details to a different table in the database that the user can return too.

This is my current Ajax function...

```
$(function() {
$("#newForm").submit(function(event){
event.preventDefault();
$('.modal').hide();
//var form = document.querySelector('#newForm'); // Find the <form> element
var formData = new FormData($("#newForm")[0]); // Wrap form contents
$('.modal').show();
//function to submit
$.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "adminChanges.php",
            data: formData,
                    dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
                    success: function(data){
                        if(data.error==''){
                            console.log(data);
                            $('#newForm')[0].reset();
                            alert('Job Saved');
                $('#myModal').hide();
              //document.location.href = 'weeklyAuditIndex.php';
                        }
              else
              {
                alert(data.error)
              }
                    },
                    error: function(data){
                        console.log(data);
              $('.modal').hide();
                    }
            });

  });
})
```

I've tried following a method where I change buttons input types from submit to buttons like so

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" name="submit_button">
<input type="button" value="Save" name="save_button">
```

And I've copied the above Ajax function, that when save_button is clicked it will post to adminChangesTemp.php. Then updated the functions to something like below

```
$("#save_button").on("click", function() {
$("#newForm").submit(function(event){
etc...
```

However nothing is now happening when I click either button.

Comment: It's unclear what you're doing after the change. Can you supply the new form of the ajax function? One thing I can tell you, after changing both inputs from `submit` to `button`, user will never trigger that submit handler.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you're using id #save_button but on input field there is no id="save_button" on Save button input

Comment: Oops, sorry, I pasted some old code. I had added the ID in to the button but still nothing happened.

Comment: It would be more useful, if we could see all of the HTML markup that relates to this and the Javascript also.